# undefined variable when Adding Dynamic Data to the View from database query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, models

I have made an admin page and user page, and i want to show the list of users who have registered in database when the admin logs in.
For that i've created a model as follows,

```
public function get_last_ten_entries()
      {
              $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM public");
              return $query->result();
      }
```

and this i am accessing through a view i have created, to which, when admin logs in, he is redirected, as follows,

```
<h1><?php echo $data;?></h1>
```

through controller,

```
  $this->load->model('loginmodel');
          $login_id = $this->loginmodel->login_valid($username, $password);
            if($login_id){
              $this->load->library('session');

              $this->session->set_userdata('user_id','$login_id');


              $data['query'] = $this->loginmodel->get_last_ten_entries();

              $this->load->view('admin/account', $data);


            }
```

but when i execute this i get,

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: data
>
> Filename: admin/account.php
>
> Line Number: 11

Comment: you use it as `$query` inside the view, you already explicitly typed it yourself, `$data['query']`, then use `foreach` like you would normally

Comment: Try this in your view,`print_r($query);die;` and you should see the data on browser.

Comment: thanks a lot himanshu ... it worked ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use $query instead of $data in the view

Answer (score 0):

**MODEL**

```
public function get_last_ten_entries()
{
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT username FROM public");
   return $query->result();
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$this->load->model('loginmodel');
$data['query'] = $this->loginmodel->get_last_ten_entries();
$login_id = $this->loginmodel->login_valid($username, $password);
if($login_id){
  $this->load->library('session');
  $this->session->set_userdata('user_id','$login_id');
  $data['query'] = $this->loginmodel->get_last_ten_entries();
  $this->load->view('admin/account', $data);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<?php 
    foreach($query as $row){
        echo $row['name'];
   }
?>
```